# Problem with checked box on wp car manager plugin

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, php, plugin-development

Hi i have a problem with wp car manager plugin. When the featured and sold checkbox are checked, when you try to uncheck and update the post type content, the checkbox always remain checked.

Any idea to sole this?

Thanks

```
/**
 * Actual meta box output
 *
 * @param \WP_Post $post
 */
public function meta_box_output( $post ) {

    // nonce
    $this->output_nonce();

    // vehicle
    $vehicle = wp_car_manager()->service( 'vehicle_factory' )->make( $post->ID );

    // load view
    wp_car_manager()->service( 'view_manager' )->display( 'meta-box/mb-data', array(
        'mb_prefix' => 'wpcm-ld',
        'vehicle'   => $vehicle,
        'fields'    => array(
            'featured'  => array(
                'type'     => 'checkbox',
                'label'    => __( 'Featured', 'wp-car-manager' ),
                'key'      => 'featured',
                'required' => false
            ),
            'sold'      => array(
                'type'     => 'checkbox',
                'label'    => __( 'Sold?', 'wp-car-manager' ),
                'key'      => 'sold',
                'required' => false
            ),
        )
    ) );

}

/**
 * Triggered on save_post
 *
 * @param int $post_id
 * @param \WP_Post $post
 */
public function save_meta_box( $post_id, $post ) {

    // check if we should save
    if ( true !== $this->should_save( $post ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // save
    if ( isset( $_POST['wpcm-ld'] ) && count( $_POST['wpcm-ld'] ) > 0 ) {

        foreach ( $_POST['wpcm-ld'] as $key => $val ) {
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpcm_' . $key, $val );
        }

        // set sold to 0 if not set (checkbox)
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['wpcm-ld']['sold'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpcm_sold', '0' );
        }

        // set featured to 0 if not set (checkbox)
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['wpcm-ld']['featured'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpcm_featured', '0' );
        }

        
        
        // call for update of vehicle order here
        $vehicle_manager = new Vehicle\Manager();
        $vehicle_manager->update_vehicle_order( $post->ID );

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Your first point of contact should be to inquire with the wp car manager development team.  I'd advise against editing their plugin - that'll just break it when you update.

Comment: Thanks for reply i try to contact them, without response in one week